# Excel import data from java table

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to import data from a table generated by java script into Excel 2010 from this webpage: https://spotwx.com/products/grib_index.php?model=nam_awphys&lat=30.26678&lon=-97.76905&tz=America/Chicago&display=table

My code (which I stole from another post and have altered) as follows:

```
Sub SpotWx_NAM()

Dim xmlHttp As Object
Dim TR_col As Object, TR As Object
Dim TD_col As Object, TD As Object
Dim row As Long, col As Long

Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
xmlHttp.Open "GET", "https://spotwx.com/products/grib_index.php?model=nam_awphys&lat=55.81035&lon=-122.26822&tz=America/Dawson_Creek&display=table", False
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
xmlHttp.send

Dim html As Object
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText

Dim tbl As Object
Set tbl = html.getElementById("example")

row = 1
col = 1

Set TR_col = html.getElementsByTagName("TR")
For Each TR In TR_col
    Set TD_col = TR.getElementsByTagName("TD")
    For Each TD In TD_col
        Cells(row, col) = TD.innerText
        col = col + 1
    Next
    col = 1
    row = row + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the problem you are facing ? Why is this tagged Java ? Do you mean JavaScript ?

Comment: You mention Java but (by viewing the source in the site you linked to) the table is clearly generated by JavaScript. But -- that doesn't really seem to be relevant. You have an HTML table which contains data you want. Excel doesn't care if it was generated by Java or JavaScript or a masochist using Notepad. I would delete all mention of Java from the question.

Answer (score 0):

The data isnt stored in a traditional HTML table so you will have to do some data gymnastics.  I would recommend leveraging regex to strip out the data you need and then parse the results.
The below code will get you part of the way there by presenting you each row in an array. I'll leave it to you to 'split' each resulting row accordingly to get each item by iterating through the rowsarray.
you will also need to trim the square brackets from the first and last array items.

```
Sub SpotWx_NAM()

Dim xmlHttp As Object
Dim TR_col As Object, TR As Object
Dim TD_col As Object, TD As Object
Dim row As Long, col As Long

Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
xmlHttp.Open "GET", "https://spotwx.com/products/grib_index.php?model=nam_awphys&lat=55.81035&lon=-122.26822&tz=America/Dawson_Creek&display=table", False
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
xmlHttp.send

Dim html As Object
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText

Dim rowsArr As Variant
rowsArr = Split(extractRows(xmlHttp.responseText), "],[", -1, 0)
For i = 0 To UBound(rowsArr)
Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(rowsArr)).Offset(i) = Split(rowsArr(i), "','")
Next
End Sub

Function extractRows(ByVal text As String) As Variant
Dim matches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim result As Variant

RE.Pattern = "\['.*'\]"
RE.Global = True
RE.IgnoreCase = True
Set matches = RE.Execute(text)

extractRows = matches(0)
End Function
```

This will get your data out into sheet 1, you'll need to clean it up a little. removing a brace from the first & last cell and a ' from the end cells.

Comment: Thanks @DaveMac but this didn't seem to do anything. No errors, no data.

Comment: Have you examined the contents of `rowsarr`? This should have all you rows of data. Put a break after the `split` and take a look. Your data should be there. You will need additional work to split the column data from each array item.

Comment: have updated the answer.  you will need to clean the data up a little but it does most of the work for you.

Comment: Thanks DaveMac. That's what I needed. I was putting the code in a module and it didn't work. then when I put it in the Sheet1 object it works great. Need to educate myself on when/where to store the code. I can take it from here!